# Java Script Пользовательский курсор

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas, cursor

Пытаюсь реализовать свой курсор по уроку.
[Custom Cursor Effects](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/01/31/custom-cursor-effects/).

Казалось бы, сделай первое второе, третье, но не работает.

На этапе "Making the Circle “Magnetic” and “Noisy”" в коде ниже начинается с *paper.view.onFrame = event =>* внешний круг исчезает, не могу понять почему. И не понимаю, как сделать внешний круг магнитным каким либо другим путём.
В html всё правильно есть ссылка с классом link. Порядок подключения скриптов верный. 
jquery, paper-core, simplex-noise, и затем мой код.

```js
let clientX = -100;
let clientY = -100;
const innerCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor--small");

const initCursor = () => {
  // add listener to track the current mouse position
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    clientX = e.clientX;
    clientY = e.clientY;
  });

  // transform the innerCursor to the current mouse position
  // use requestAnimationFrame() for smooth performance
  const render = () => {
    innerCursor.style.transform = `translate(${clientX}px, ${clientY}px)`;
    // if you are already using TweenMax in your project, you might as well
    // use TweenMax.set() instead
    // TweenMax.set(innerCursor, {
    //   x: clientX,
    //   y: clientY
    // });

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
let isStuck = false;
let showCursor = false;
let group, stuckX, stuckY, fillOuterCursor;

const initCanvas = () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector(".cursor--canvas");
  const shapeBounds = {
    width: 75,
    height: 75
  };
  paper.setup(canvas);
  const strokeColor = "rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.4)";
  const strokeWidth = 1;
  const segments = 8;
  const radius = 15;

  // we'll need these later for the noisy circle
  const noiseScale = 150; // speed
  const noiseRange = 4; // range of distortion
  let isNoisy = false; // state

  // the base shape for the noisy circle
  const polygon = new paper.Path.RegularPolygon(
    new paper.Point(0, 0),
    segments,
    radius
  );
  polygon.strokeColor = strokeColor;
  polygon.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
  polygon.smooth();
  group = new paper.Group([polygon]);
  group.applyMatrix = false;

  const noiseObjects = polygon.segments.map(() => new SimplexNoise());
  let bigCoordinates = [];

  // function for linear interpolation of values
  const lerp = (a, b, n) => {
    return (1 - n) * a + n * b;
  };

  // function to map a value from one range to another range
  const map = (value, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => {
    return (
      ((value - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
    );
  };

  // the draw loop of Paper.js
  // (60fps with requestAnimationFrame under the hood)
  paper.view.onFrame = event => {
    // using linear interpolation, the circle will move 0.2 (20%)
    // of the distance between its current position and the mouse
    // coordinates per Frame
    lastX = lerp(lastX, clientX, 0.2);
    lastY = lerp(lastY, clientY, 0.2);
    group.position = new paper.Point(lastX, lastY);
  };
};

const initHovers = () => {

 // find the center of the link element and set stuckX and stuckY
 // these are needed to set the position of the noisy circle
 const handleMouseEnter = e => {
   const navItem = e.currentTarget;
   const navItemBox = navItem.getBoundingClientRect();
   stuckX = Math.round(navItemBox.left + navItemBox.width / 2);
   stuckY = Math.round(navItemBox.top + navItemBox.height / 2);
   isStuck = true;
 };
 
 // reset isStuck on mouseLeave
 const handleMouseLeave = () => {
   isStuck = false;
 };
 
 // add event listeners to all items
 const linkItems = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
 linkItems.forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener("mouseenter", handleMouseEnter);
   item.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);
 });
  };
  
// the draw loop of Paper.js
// (60fps with requestAnimationFrame under the hood)
paper.view.onFrame = event => {
 // using linear interpolation, the circle will move 0.2 (20%)
 // of the distance between its current position and the mouse
 // coordinates per Frame
 if (!isStuck) {
   // move circle around normally
   lastX = lerp(lastX, clientX, 0.2);
   lastY = lerp(lastY, clientY, 0.2);
   group.position = new paper.Point(lastX, lastY);
 } else if (isStuck) {
   // fixed position on a nav item
   lastX = lerp(lastX, stuckX, 0.2);
   lastY = lerp(lastY, stuckY, 0.2);
   group.position = new paper.Point(lastX, lastY);
 }
 
 if (isStuck && polygon.bounds.width < shapeBounds.width) { 
   // scale up the shape 
   polygon.scale(1.08);
 } else if (!isStuck && polygon.bounds.width > 30) {
   // remove noise
   if (isNoisy) {
  polygon.segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
    segment.point.set(bigCoordinates[i][0], bigCoordinates[i][1]);
  });
  isNoisy = false;
  bigCoordinates = [];
   }
   // scale down the shape
   const scaleDown = 0.92;
   polygon.scale(scaleDown);
 }
 
 // while stuck and big, apply simplex noise
 if (isStuck && polygon.bounds.width >= shapeBounds.width) {
   isNoisy = true;
   // first get coordinates of large circle
   if (bigCoordinates.length === 0) {
  polygon.segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
    bigCoordinates[i] = [segment.point.x, segment.point.y];
  });
   }
   
   // loop over all points of the polygon
   polygon.segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
  
  // get new noise value
  // we divide event.count by noiseScale to get a very smooth value
  const noiseX = noiseObjects[i].noise2D(event.count / noiseScale, 0);
  const noiseY = noiseObjects[i].noise2D(event.count / noiseScale, 1);
  
  // map the noise value to our defined range
  const distortionX = map(noiseX, -1, 1, -noiseRange, noiseRange);
  const distortionY = map(noiseY, -1, 1, -noiseRange, noiseRange);
  
  // apply distortion to coordinates
  const newX = bigCoordinates[i][0] + distortionX;
  const newY = bigCoordinates[i][1] + distortionY;
  
  // set new (noisy) coodrindate of point
  segment.point.set(newX, newY);
   });
   
 }
 polygon.smooth();
  };

initCursor();
initCanvas();
initHovers();
```